# React-Select component not displaying values stored within Formik's state values

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-select

I am using `react-select` within a MUI stepper together with Formik.

My values for the react-select component are stored correctly within Formik's state but when I go back a step and then forward again (mui stepper), my `react-select` component loses the values even though it's still in Formik's state.

Just displays the placeholder value - "Fields".

My code is as follows:

```
import ReactSelect from 'react-select';

  const myFields = [
    { field_id: 0, field_name: 'field_name_0' },
    { field_id: 1, field_name: 'field_name_1' },
    { field_id: 2, field_name: 'field_name_2' },
    { field_id: 3, field_name: 'field_name_3' },
    { field_id: 4, field_name: 'field_name_4' },
    { field_id: 5, field_name: 'field_name_5' },
  ];

                <ReactSelect
                  isMulti={true}
                  name="selectedFields"
                  id="sel"
                  placeholder="Fields"
                  options={myFields.map((field) => ({
                    value: field,
                    label: field.field_name
                  }))}
                  onChange={(fieldSel) => {
                    setFieldValue(
                      'selectedFields',
                      fieldSel.map((field) => field.value)
                    );
                  }}
                />
```

Here are the selected fields within Formik's state:

```
"selectedFields": [
            {
                "field_id": 0,
                "field_name": "field_name_0"
            },
            {
                "field_id": 1,
                "field_name": "field_name_1"
            },
            {
                "field_id": 2,
                "field_name": "field_name_2"
            }
        ],
```

All seems fine at selection but unsure why my `<ReactSelect />` component doesn't re-display the values from Formik's state (`selectedFields`) when going back and forth through MUI's stepper.

Not sure what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never set the value for the react-select. Try something like this:

```
 <ReactSelect
      options={myFields.map((field) => ({
        value: field,
        label: field.field_name
      }))}
      value={selectedFields.map(field => ({label: field.field_name, value: field}))
      onChange={(fieldSel) => {
        setFieldValue(
        'selectedFields',
        fieldSel.map((field) => field.value));
      }}
  />
```

Comment: Good pickup - that did it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method:**

store value in state and display that value in select,
using **formik.setFieldValue** method set the id in formik state

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState("");

const handleSelectChange = (e) => {       
   setUser(e.target.value);
   formik.setFieldValue('owner', e.target?.value) // set formik value
};

<Select
        displayEmpty
        name="owner"
        value={user}
        onChange={(e) => handleSelectChange(e)}
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Case Onwer' }}
      >   
       
        {users && users?.map((user) => {
          return (
            <MenuItem key={user.id} value={user.id}>{`${user.full_name} [ ${user.email} ]`}</MenuItem>
          )
        })}
</Select>
```